# Submit form with jQuery to iframe feedback when done?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

For a photo upload I submit a form to an iframe.

### The form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_images.php" target="iframe_pp_upload" id="dd_form">
   <input type="file" id="dd_upload" name="file">
</form>
```

### The iframe

```
<iframe name="iframe_pp_upload" src="not-yet-submitted.php"></iframe>
```

### The jQuery

```
$('#dd_upload').change(function() {
  $('#dd_form').submit();
});
```

The `upload_images.php` uploads the image. However, what is the best way to get a feedback when the upload is done?

Answer (score 0):

Do this output in the upload_images.php:

```
file header......
    <script>
         window.parent.uploadReady(); 
    </script>

.....
```

And in the main window, there must be an js function uploadReady(), and there you can do what you want.

```
function uploadReady() {
      alert("im in the parent window");
 }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: thx, Kay. The question is, if I output your code in the iframe, the alert will fire immediately on page load. How can I know when the upload is ready?